# Silverstripe Core upgrade from 3.5.6 to 3.6.6

Tags: php, composer-php, silverstripe

I have a website built on Silverstripe 3.5.6 and I need to update it to 3.6.6 because it has php 7.0.

The documentation is very twisted and I don't understand anything. Basically what I tried was to open composer.json and change framework,cms versions from 3.5.6 to 3.6.6 and then via Terminal launch the "composer update" command, and I tought this will load the corresponding versions, but I get this error back:

```
   - Installation request for silverstripe/framework 3.6.6@stable -> satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[3.6.6].
- silverstripe/framework 3.6.6 requires php >= 5.3.3, <7.2 -> your PHP version (7.2.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- Installation request for silverstripe/reports 3.6.6@stable -> 
 satisfiable by silverstripe/reports[3.6.6].
- silverstripe/reports 3.6.6 requires php >=5.3.3,<7.2 -> your PHP 
version (7.2.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
 Problem 3
 - silverstripe/framework 3.6.6 requires php >= 5.3.3, <7.2 -> your PHP 
  version (7.2.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - silverstripe/display-logic 1.5.0 requires silverstripe/framework 
  ^3.1 
 -> satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[3.6.6].
- Installation request for silverstripe/display-logic 1.5.0 -> satisfiable by silverstripe/display-logic[1.5.0].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the log you posted:

> silverstripe/framework 3.6.6 requires php >= 5.3.3, <7.2 -> your PHP 
>     version (7.2.11) does not satisfy that requirement.

Silverstripe 3.x (prior to 3.7.0) only supports PHP 7 versions [*before* 7.2](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/getting_started/server_requirements/). If you want to use PHP 7.2, you will need to upgrade to [SilverStripe 3.7+](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/changelogs/3.7.0/) or [Silverstripe 4.x](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/server_requirements/).

Comment: Thank you @kungphu, that's a bit odd, it should be php 7.1 there because it's a vhost. I will look into it later today. Anyhow, the way I tried to updates SS, is it supposed to work ?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know; I've never worked with Silverstripe. I would certainly review whatever other dependencies you are managing via Composer, though, to make sure you're are the latest that are compatible with both each other and whichever version of PHP you end up using. Also, check the release notes to make sure you're aware of any changes to your own code that might be necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will get back on this one later today, I am busy with something else at the moment, but if it was just a php version issue and after that it works, I will also mark your answer as correct. :)

Comment: Done it, successfully upgraded to 3.6.6 - thank you.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include SilverStripe 3.7, which is also compatible with PHP 7.2. Upgrading from 3.6.x to 3.7.x should be painless. Maybe you'd have to install newer versions of modules/addons as well, since not all are PHP 7.2 compatible.

Comment: Thank you, @bummzack. I think I failed to find the most current/relevant documentation.